# Adf- First Row of file-Header or not

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a folder with pipe delaminated txt files and in the pipeline we go through the list of files in a  foreach loop. Within the foreach loop we have a data flow where the source gets the dataset and dataset specifies that the first row of the file is the header. Source is drifted schema.

What I want to know is if the first row of the file is not in the correct format, for example if it does not have pipes to separate the rows, that is a bad file. Without pipes, the header is not in the first row of the txt file. Hence its a bad file.

I dont want it to go through the data flow (source to sink) rather it throws an error and goes into a reject folder (sink) operation.

How can I go about error handling for bad formatted header files, checking the first row is good for pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing the file names to Dataflow activity using ForEach activity, you can try the below method which involves lookup before the dataflow activity inside ForEach.

Inside ForEach activity, take a lookup activity. For this lookup activity you should give the delimited dataset with following configurations.

[image]

Here, we are using the lookup to get the header of the pipe delimited text file in a string. Then you can check the header with an if activity and if its results `True`, use dataflow activity and if `False`, don't use dataflow on it.

In the lookup activity, select `First Row`.

[image]

This gives file header like this in each iteration.

[image]

Now, use this string to check the file header in if activity. Here, for sample I am checking whether the header contains `pipe(|)` or not. Use this header `activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0` as per your required condition.

```
@contains(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0, '|')
```

[image]

Here for demo, I have used set variable activities inside True and False activities of if activities.

For you, inside If **True activities**, add your **dataflow activity** and pass the file path using ForEach `@item()`.  In the False activities of if, you can add any activity to handle the bad files. But, don't use the same dataset which we used for Lookup activity for the dataflow.

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, that was a perfect solution.  It worked like a charm!
I just posted another adf question, in case you are interested in helping out there as well.